# replaceWith if Id matches - not working

Tags: jquery

I have a simple header that I would like to populate with a City Name if it matches an ID. I am currently using `replaceWith` and it only seems to work on the first time.  Not sure why?

Here is the function:

```
function toggleDetails() {
    $(".pin").click(function() {
        var cityName =  $(this).attr('id');
        $(".city-details").toggle();

        if (cityName === 'Miami') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Miami");
        }
        else if(cityName === 'Philadelphia') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Philadelphia");
        }
        else if (cityName === 'Chicago') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Chicago");
        }
        else if (cityName === 'Los-Angeles') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Los Angeles");
        }
        else if (cityName === 'Houston') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Houston");
        }
        else if (cityName === 'San-Diego'){
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("San Diego");
        }
        else if (cityName === 'Atlanta') {
            $('h3#cityName').replaceWith("Atlanta");
        }
        console.log(cityName);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="pin totally newyork" id="NewYork">
    New York
</p>
<p class="pin barely boston" id="Boston">
    Boston
</p>
<p class="pin fairly philadelphia" id="Philadelphia">
    Philadelphia
</p>
<p class="pin barely chicago" id="Chicago">
    Chicago
</p>
<p class="pin barely la" id="Los-Angeles">
    Los Angeles
</p>
<p class="pin fairly houston" id="Houston">
    Houston
</p>
```

Comment: When and how is `toggleDetails()` being called?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, are you trying to add h3 tag with id or try to replace the existed one. And if you just want to change the text why don t you just use $(this).text();

Comment: instead replaeWith try $('h3#cityName').html("your text");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceWith` will remove the element and replace it with the given text, hence there's no longer an element to be replaced after the first time. Try with `.text` or `.html`. Also your code seems a little redundant as well.

```
$(".pin").click(function() {
    $(".city-details").toggle();
    $('#cityName').text(this.id.replace(/-/g, ' '));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bBEtA/)

Answer (score 0):

replaceWith will replace the entire DOM element with the new content. This means after the first invocation, there is no longer a 'h3' in the DOM, and therefore subsequent invocations won't find an element matching the `$('h3#cityName')` selector to do anything with.

Try `.text("NewCityName")` instead of replaceWith

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the entire element with the text, so when you want to replace again the element doesn't exist any more.

Just replace the text in the element. Example:

```
 $('h3#cityName').text("Miami");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there an h3 element with id cityname ? It is not shown in your code. 
If there are different such elements you will need to use

```
$('h3#' + cityName)
```

In any case, replaceWith will "each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content.". In your case you might want to set the html() or text() of your target element.

```
$('h3#cityName').html("Chicago");
```

Comment: Thought that at first too, but cityName seems to be an id that is not shown in the sample code.